# How to Run Multiple Time Same Code in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, repeat

How can i run multiple times this same code? For example 12 times?

```
 sed -n 1,1p 00-02.txt | sed -e 's/^/<video length="-1" src="mp4:/' \
                          -e 's/$/" start="0"><\/video>/' >>playlist.txt

    echo -e "$(sed -e '1,1d' 00-02.txt)\n" > 00-02.txt

    cat 00-02.txt | sed '/^$/d' >> 00-02a.txt

    rm 00-02.txt

    mv 00-02a.txt 00-02.txt

    sed -n 1,1p spot.txt | sed -e 's/^/<video length="-1" src="mp4:/' \
                          -e 's/$/" start="0"><\/video>/' >>playlist.txt

    echo -e "$(sed -e '1,1d' spot.txt)\n" > spot.txt

    cat spot.txt | sed '/^$/d' >> spota.txt

    rm spot.txt

mv spota.txt spot.txt
```

**All the code belove** must be **replicated N times**

something like

```
for n in {1..12}; **ALL THE COMMANDS BELOVE**; done
```

But it does not work for multiple lines of command.

Any issue?

Comment: I should work in a for loop, can you explain what you mean by does not work for multiple lines? do you get an error or do you get the wrong  result?

Comment: Thanks @Ajay solved in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `while` loop and a counter:

```
#!/bin/bash

iterations=12
count=0

while [ "$count" -lt "$iterations" ]
do
    sed -n 1,1p 00-02.txt | sed -e 's/^/<video length="-1" src="mp4:/' \
                      -e 's/$/" start="0"><\/video>/' >>playlist.txt

    echo -e "$(sed -e '1,1d' 00-02.txt)\n" > 00-02.txt

    cat 00-02.txt | sed '/^$/d' >> 00-02a.txt

    rm 00-02.txt

    mv 00-02a.txt 00-02.txt

    sed -n 1,1p spot.txt | sed -e 's/^/<video length="-1" src="mp4:/' \
                      -e 's/$/" start="0"><\/video>/' >>playlist.txt

    echo -e "$(sed -e '1,1d' spot.txt)\n" > spot.txt

    cat spot.txt | sed '/^$/d' >> spota.txt

    rm spot.txt

    mv spota.txt spot.txt
    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `seq`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 12) ; do echo $i ; done
```

It's not a builtin, but it's a pretty common utility.